# Anyone offer a better solution? Right to left regex. using python

Tags: python, regex, ab-initio

First of all happy Independence Day!  for those who apply!

I´m analyzing an Ab Initio graphs, for that, I need to obtain the name of the component, the one  that the developer used to describe it´s functionality, which I can extract from the following line.

```
name ='}}@0|@207000|80000|227000|100000|152000|126000|11654|RFMT: Generate Labels Header|Ab Initio Software|Built-in|1|100|0||6||32769|1|{1|0|}}}'
```

I tried to use regex to extract the name of the component which is: **RFMT: Generate Labels Header**.

There comes the problem:

My delimiter is **|Ab Initio Software** that means, I need to use regex from right to left.
is there any way to acomplish that using Python.

The most eficient solution I have came up with is to reverse everything.

```
name = line[::-1]
name = re.search('erawtfoS oitinI bA\|(.*?)\|', name, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
name = name[::-1]
```

All I want is to make it more efficient because is going to be used on hundreds of graphs and most of those files are quite large.

Comment: If your component name contains at least one letter, this regex could work: [^|]*[a-zA-Z]+[^|]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just match non-`|` characters and use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure it's the element before `Ab Initio...`:

```
re.search(r'(?<=[|])[^|]*(?=[|]Ab Initio Software)', name, re.IGNORECASE).group()
```

Even without the lookahead, if you just change `(.*?)` to the more explicit `[^|]*`, you'd get the right result. But the greedy lookahead solution might be more efficient. Anyway, here it is:

```
re.search(r'[|]([^|]*)[|]Ab Initio Software', name, re.IGNORECASE).group(1)
```

Comment: Wow So I really need to know more about regex.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KarTo the tutorial from which I linked the section about lookarounds it's definitely worth reading if you want to improve your regex skills.